# Unable to Unrar in Google Colab

Tags: google-colaboratory

I'm using Google Colab to learn and tinker with ML and TensorFlow. I had a huge dataset in multiple multi-part rar files. I tried simply

!unrar e zip-file 'extdir'

but after successfully extracting a couple of archives it starts throwing up errors, specifically input/output errors.

Does google block you after a couple GBs unrar-ed?

I have already tried resetting the runtime environment and changing the runtime from Py2 to Py3 but nothing made a difference

Comment: it would probably be good to provide the exact error that you are getting so that the community can help you more effectively

Comment: I did mention it, I am getting Input/output error, cannot read file

Answer (score 0):

True, it doesn't work after a couple of runs.
Try unrar-free, the free version of unrar.
Checkout the help manual below:
https://helpmanual.io/help/unrar-free/

Answer (score 0):

No Google doesn't block you for extracting large files. Also, unrar-free gave the same error as before. So, you can **install p7zip** and extract rarv5. Or you can also use 7z. This solved the exact same problem that I was also facing. (I had a rar file ~20 GiB).

```
!apt install p7zip-full p7zip-rar
```

or

`!7z e zip-file`